# Running a block after several calls to loadFileRepresentation have finished

Tags: ios, thread-safety

I’m using the NSItemProvider method `loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: completionHandler:)`. This method asynchronously writes some data to a temporary file and immediately returns a Progress object representing the progress of this write. It also accepts a block that will be called when the temporary file has been written and is ready for you to use. (The block is also called if there’s an error preparing the file.)

I am going to be calling this method several times in succession and want to display a “please wait” message in my UI until each of my blocks has finished. How can I do this in a thread-safe way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display a dialog with a “please wait” message. Then iterate through the extension context’s `inputItems` twice: once just to count the number of files we want to process and then again to actually process them. When the number of files processed is equal to the number we expected, we call another instance method to hide the dialog and return control to the host app.

For thread safety, the incrementing of the number processed and the comparison between the number processed and the number expected are done on a serial `DispatchQueue`. This ensures that even if multiple copies of the block passed to `loadFileRepresentation` are run at the same time, the extension will still be able to correctly identify when it is done processing files.

```swift
import UIKit

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let items = extensionContext?.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem] else {
            return
        }

        // Display a "please wait" message while we copy the files.

        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: nil,
                                        message: "Processing files…",
                                        preferredStyle: .alert)
        present(alertVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

        // Iterate through the files once, incrementing "numberExpected" each
        // time we see a file we're interested in.

        var numberExpected: Int = 0

        for item in items {
            guard let attachments = item.attachments else {
                continue
            }

            for attachment in attachments {
                if attachmentShouldBeProcessed(attachment) {
                    numberExpected += 1
                }
            }
        }

        // Iterate through the files again, actually processing them this time.
        // After each file is done--whether it succeeded or not--we increment
        // "numberProcessed" and compare it to "numberExpected". (It's very
        // important that this be done in a thread-safe way, which we accomplish
        // here by doing the comparison within a block that is run on a serial
        // DispatchQueue.) If they're equal, call the finish() method to close
        // the progress dialog and return control of the UI to the host app.

        var numberProcessed: Int = 0
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myapp.file-processing-queue")

        for item in items {
            guard let attachments = item.attachments else {
                continue
            }

            for attachment in attachments {
                guard attachmentShouldBeProcessed(attachment) else {
                    continue
                }
                attachment.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.png") { url, error in

                    // ...your business logic here...

                    queue.sync {
                        numberProcessed += 1
                        if numberProcessed == numberExpected {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                                self?.finish()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func finish() {
        // Dismiss the "processing items" dialog.
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        // Inform the host app that we're done so it can un-block its UI.
        extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    func attachmentShouldBeProcessed(_ attachment: NSItemProvider) -> Bool {
        // ...your business logic here...
        return true
    }
}
```